# how to use @MailSessionAnnotation in my javamail web application?

Tags: jakarta-mail

There is no reliable reference in this domain, at least i didn't find in my google search. How to apply user authentication in JavaEE aplication ?

Someone told me to use the @MailSessionDefenition annotation, but actually i didn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, you can only use it in Java EE 7 application servers, e.g., GlassFish 4.0.  I believe the Java EE SDK has a sample application that shows how to use it.  Let me know if you can't find it.

The big advantage of @MailSessionDefinition is that the deployer can override the configuration if necessary.  If that's not important to you, you can always just create the Session yourself using properties.

Comment: Thank you, i downloaded the sdk samples and found some useful examples